# Are there creatures besides humans and jinns in paradise and hell?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, jannah, christianity, jahannam, judaism

From Islamic scriptures, it is known that the inhabitants of paradise and hell will consist of humans, jinns, hoors and angels.

But there is a verse in the Quran in *Surah Al Isra*:

> وَلَقَدْ كَرَّمْنَا بَنِي آدَمَ وَحَمَلْنَاهُمْ فِي الْبَرِّ
> وَالْبَحْرِ وَرَزَقْنَاهُمْ مِنَ الطَّيِّبَاتِ وَفَضَّلْنَاهُمْ عَلَىٰ
> كَثِيرٍ مِمَّنْ خَلَقْنَا تَفْضِيلًا
>
> And We have certainly honored the children of Adam and carried them on
> the land and sea and provided for them of the good things and
> preferred them *over much of what We have created*, with [definite]
> preference.
> **Source**: https://quran.com/17/70

Are there any sahih hadiths or any other Islamic or Judeo-Christian references where God talks about the fate of those who have been preferred over us?

Do they have free will and will they be held accountable on the Day of Judgement or not?

Comment: I recall reading somewhere that it is not certain that jinn will be in paradise, it is only certain that evil jinn will be in hell. Also that everything else will turn to dust after Hisab on the Day of Qiyamah.

Comment: @Ryan W.r.t to the second part of your comment, I remember reading that animals will turn to dust after Hisab on the Day of Qiyamah. I'm not sure if I read about anything else.

Comment: I am not sure I understand above verse clearly but if they are creations that preferred over us then who are they? And Allah Knows best.

Comment: Ahmed, looks like you misinterpreted the verse. It's not affirming there are other creatures preferred over humans. It's saying humans themselves are the preferred creatures!

Comment: @Muslimahياربالعالمين - "preferred them over much of what We have created" ... to me the translation sounds like God has preferred humans over much (not all) of what He has created. Is my understanding incorrect?